# Blocking DC without blocking any frequencies?

Tags: capacitor, rf, ac, filter

Is there any practical way of blocking DC without blocking any AC frequencies (or as few as possible)? Suppose I wanted to block DC and let through all frequencies between 2Hz and 10Ghz with minimum resistance.

The first methods that spring to mind would be to either use a very large capacitor or many capacitors in parallel with different values adjusted for different frequencies.

Is there something blatantly obvious I've missed?

Comment: Where does AC end and DC begin?

Comment: By "as few as possible", what are we talking here? There are an infinite number of AC frequencies in any band you choose to pick. Does it really matter if it blocks 1Hz? 1mHz? 1uHz? 1nHz (31 years per cycle!)? Please update your question and be realistic...

Comment: I admit – I was a bit unclear: how would one block DC while still letting through, say 2Hz - 10GHz? A very large bandpass filter?

Comment: So you have no problem working with an amplifier/circuit with a bandwidth of 10 GHz (give or take two Hz), but you don't know how to couple a signal into it? I think the coupling cap is least of the challenges you'll face.

Comment: At 10GHz, none of your passive components (including wire) are going to behave like their ideal counterparts. What on earth are you doing that requires a 2Hz-10GHz bandwidth?

Comment: I'm not "doing" anything – It's a theoretical question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you asked for "practical" methods, I'll provide an answer which differs somewhat from the others.

Yes, a capacitor (followed by a resistor) will block the DC component of a signal. And yes, if you want low-frequency rejection you'll need a big capacitor.

But, and this is a big but, large capacitors by their nature are physically large and have large inductive components. This interferes with high-frequency performance, and I seriously doubt that you'll find a unit which will give you 2 Hz to 10 GHz. About 3 orders of magnitude is a reasonable goal for low price. See [here, for instance](http://www.pasternack.com/dc-blocks-category.aspx) for a line of RF DC blocks with a good unit reaching from 10 MHz to 40 GHz. If you're willing to spend the bucks, there are specialty manufacturers such as Picosecond Pulse Labs (now part of Tektronix) which [provide 7 kHz to 26 GHz](http://www.tek.com/components/dc-blocks). A Google on DC block will provide other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When you say that a standard low-end capacitor probably wouldn't "give me" 2Hz - 10GHz – what do you mean exactly? You mean it won't block all DC? Won't let through the highest frequencies?

Comment: A series cap will have a low-frequency cutoff set by capacitance and load resistance. It will have a high-frequency cutoff set by inductance and load. The overall curve will then "give" a response between these two limits. The two cutoff frequencies are generally identified by some fraction of the bandpass response, such as -3 dB or -1 dB. See data sheets for details. Usually DC cutoff is very good and clean: making a low-leakage cap is pretty simple. Upper cutoff behavior may be more complicated: it depends on the factors involved. And oh yes, wait 24 hours before selecting an answer.

Answer (score 4):

A single series capacitor isn't enough - you need a resistor on the output to prevent capacitor leakage putting DC on the output: -

[image]

The 3dB point is defined in formula form as Fc = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}\$

So, with R = 100 kohm and C = 100 uF, Fc is 0.0159 Hz

If you wanted to use those values and see what effect that might have on passing (say) 1Hz use this formula: -

[image]

Where \$\omega = 2\pi f\$ and for this formula f is the frequency you want to test i.e. 1 Hz as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one series capacitor, selected for the lowest pass frequency. Higher frequencies will pass with less impedance.

Comment: Theoretically, yes.  In practice, no.

Comment: i fail to see how, in practice, a capacitor of finite capacitance in series does not block DC.  and the bigger the capacitance, the lower is the cutoff frequency.

Comment: How about a 0.1uF capacitor that goes up to 40GHz? and down to 2Hz with a 1M load. http://www.rf-microwave.com/en/shop/0/153-ultra-broadband-capacitors-up-to-40-ghz/1614-CCB-100N.html

Answer (score 0):

In theory an infinitely narrow slit in a transmission line will block DC and pass all AC... at least until the width of the split becomes significant on an atomic scale.

In practice, there is no transmission line which can pass all AC. So the DC block is only half the problem. The other half is finding a suitable transmission line to carry the signal from either side of the DC block.... PCB traces, coax cables, and waveguides each have a frequency response.

Anyway, you are not missing anything simple. Every low pass filter has a roll off, and so there will be significant low frequency attenuation. The practical answer is to determine exactly the lowest and highest frequencies of interest and the acceptable insertion loss, then design / buy a low pass filter to suit.

Answer (score -2):

I may be wrong but I think you can simply let the signal go through a capacitor, this will remove all the DC part.I understand that many caps are needed because your application is 'DC to daylight" Rule of thumb is one cap per decade. I don't know the optimal value of  capacitance though.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without knowing the impedance of the load.  You need the impedance of the capacitor to be significantly less than that of the load at the lowest frequency you want to let through.